# chrome ios application cache does not clear

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage, offline

I'm building a web app with offline capabilities and it doesn't appear that Chrome (iOS) clears localstorage properly. I've cleared all the data in the settings but it keeps using the first version that I tested with.

Clearing the data works fine in Safari so it appears it's an issue with Chrome.

Does anyone know if this is a bug with Chrome on the iOS and localstorage? I'm only using the manifest file at this point.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mainfest, that means you are using application cache. So have a try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_offline_cache

Or you could modify manifest file to force the browser update the page. By the way local storage is different from application cache.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. So it appears application cache on the iOS chrome app does not clear or check the manifest for newer versions.